# How to list multi-dimensional arrays values in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So first off, sorry if this appears if I am asking you to do my homework...just me you are not, this question only involves one tiny little aspect of the entire program that is in the making...In other words this isn't close to be finished.

I would ask my teacher, but its an online course. So then I would ask my friends for advice, but I'm the only kid in my school taking this computer science course. (It's a small school)

Anyways this program when completed, will allow a teacher to input a list of students of four grades per student. Eventually I'll add some code that allows the teacher to find the averages of each student etc etc.

However at the moment I'm only in the process of listing students. Where there is a small problem...

Every time I list a student (their last and first name) along with the four test scores, it all outputs nicely. However when I go to output the second student with a different name and different test scores, it outs the different name...but the test scores of the previous student.

Ex.

John Smith: 67 68 57 87

Jane Doe: 67 68 57 87 (even though it should Jane Doe: 54 68 75 91)

And clearly that is a problem...since all students do not have the exact same grades...ever..

Okay code below...

```
public class StudentGradesView extends FrameView {
    int [][] aryStudent = new int [15][4]; //[15] being number of students and [4] being test scores...
    String[] studentNames = new String[15]; // I'm thinking this is might unnecessary now...but we'll see
    int numOfStudents = 0; //starting number of students at 0....

    int marks = 0;

    int test1;
    int test2;
    int test3;
    int test4;

    public StudentGradesView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
        //unimportant...just stuff added for GUI..
    }

    private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //test1Field through test4Field are the test scores....
        aryStudent[numOfStudents][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
        aryStudent[numOfStudents][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
        aryStudent[numOfStudents][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
        aryStudent[numOfStudents][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int x=0; x < numOfStudents ; x++) {
            sb.append(firstNameField.getText() + " " + lastNameField.getText());
            for (int y=0; y < 4; y++) {
                sb.append(" " +aryStudent[x][y]);
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        studentListField.setText(sb.toString());
        numOfStudents ++;
    }                                        
}
```

Comment: How about adding the value of `numOfStudents` and `x` as debug output, so you can trace the problem better.

Comment: You are not storing the student names anywhere.  Each time they push the button, it gets the current student name, but doesn't appear to save it.  It just writes it out to studentFieldList with the other data, but that is overwritten every time the button is pushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you want

```
for (int x=0; x<= numOfStudents; x++)
```

or when numOfStudents = 0 you'll never go into the loop.

Also, does addButtonActionPerformed have a for loop that contains the code you've given us? Otherwise, it seems like every time you go into that method numOfStudents will be 0 and when you exit it'll be 1, but the code is only executed for numOfStudents = 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is a "numOfStudents++;" after the loop, I believe that would change how it originally equals 0 each time would it not? Also that added equal sign in the first loop did solve my test score problem, however now it keeps the same name for every student but different grades. If I were to use my string "String[] studentNames = new String[15];" and add studentNames[numOfStudents] = firstNameField.getText() + " " + lastNameField.getText();""  somewhere in my loop, do you think that would solve the new name problem?

Comment: Condition x<=numOfStudents will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when x=15. for safer you can have (x<=numOfStudents && x<15)

Comment: Where do you actually populate aryStudent with names?

Comment: Well the only thing I have connecting with the names would be firstNameField and lastNameField which are inputted along with the test scores. Only whenever I add a different test score along with the student name, all the previous names change to the most recented added name. The nameField 's are only used in the loop for the outputted sentence...

Comment: Wait...if i were to actually use this string which is not in use atm..." String[] studentNames = new String[15];" but near the end of the loop do "studentNames++;" like I did numOfStudents..would that work...? Even though I would have modified it in some way to work for a string?